# Parsing XML in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, iso

I have this requirement where I am trying to build SQL queries on teradata and pull XML attributes/element data.
The dataset I am working on is a swift iso payment xmlsnlike PAC04,PACS08,etc.

I looked at teradata doc and started using XMLEXTRACT, but there are issues I am facing.

How do I ignore namespaces, now namespaces can have a variety.I tried wildcard but it did not work.

**Adding sample XML**

Now the issue I am facing is that the namespace here is PACS, but this can vary as any alphanumeric word. I need to use the final query in a view so that user can just query on view.

```
<pacs:Document xmlns:pacs="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.009.001.08" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <pacs:FICdtTrf>
        <pacs:GrpHdr>
            <pacs:MsgId>XXXXXXXXX</pacs:MsgId>
            <pacs:CreDtTm>2022-09-12T10:18:09+08:00</pacs:CreDtTm>
            <pacs:NbOfTxs>1</pacs:NbOfTxs>
            <pacs:SttlmInf>
                <pacs:SttlmMtd>CLRG</pacs:SttlmMtd>
                <pacs:ClrSys>
                    <pacs:Cd>MEP</pacs:Cd>
                </pacs:ClrSys>
            </pacs:SttlmInf>
        </pacs:GrpHdr>
        <pacs:CdtTrfTxInf>
            <pacs:PmtId>
                <pacs:InstrId>YYYYYYYYY</pacs:InstrId>
                <pacs:EndToEndId>ZZZZZZZZ</pacs:EndToEndId>
                <pacs:UETR>UETRRRRR</pacs:UETR>
            </pacs:PmtId>
            <pacs:IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="INR">10000</pacs:IntrBkSttlmAmt>
            <pacs:IntrBkSttlmDt>2022-09-12</pacs:IntrBkSttlmDt>
            <pacs:InstgAgt>
                <pacs:FinInstnId>
                    <pacs:BICFI>BICXXXX</pacs:BICFI>
                </pacs:FinInstnId>
            </pacs:InstgAgt>
            <pacs:InstdAgt>
                <pacs:FinInstnId>
                    <pacs:BICFI>BICZZZZZ</pacs:BICFI>
                </pacs:FinInstnId>
            </pacs:InstdAgt>
            <pacs:Dbtr>
                <pacs:FinInstnId>
                    <pacs:BICFI>BIXYYYYY</pacs:BICFI>
                </pacs:FinInstnId>
            </pacs:Dbtr>
            <pacs:CdtrAgt>
                <pacs:FinInstnId>
                    <pacs:BICFI>BICOOOOOO</pacs:BICFI>
                </pacs:FinInstnId>
            </pacs:CdtrAgt>
            <pacs:Cdtr>
                <pacs:FinInstnId>
                    <pacs:BICFI>BICPPPPPPPP</pacs:BICFI>
                </pacs:FinInstnId>
            </pacs:Cdtr>
        </pacs:CdtTrfTxInf>
    </pacs:FICdtTrf>
</pacs:Document>
```

**My Attempt**

```
SELECT X.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM DB_NAME.TABLE_NAME) AS C,
   XMLTable (
      '/Document/FICdtTrf/GrpHdr'
      PASSING C.PACS_XML
      COLUMNS

           "Seqno" FOR ORDINALITY,
           "MsgId" VARCHAR(35) PATH '//MsgId',
           "CreDtTm" VARCHAR(35) PATH '//CreDtTm',
           "NbOfTxs" VARCHAR(35) PATH '//NbOfTxs',
           "SttlmAmt" VARCHAR(12) PATH '../CdtTrfTxInf/IntrBkSttlmAmt'

   ) AS X ("Sequence #", "MSG_ID", "CREATION_TMP", "TXN_COUNT", "SttlmAmt");
```

Comment: please show an actual xml, your attempts and explain what ae the problems you are facing

Comment: @nbk Added the sample and attempt.

Comment: and your Problem=

Comment: The query is not returning the result, I can hardcode namespace prefix as 'pacs' but then this value can vary. I just don't want to hardcode, rather need a way to escape it or have a wildcard!

Comment: sql is not made for that, you will need dynamic sql for such things

Comment: But then teradata allows parsing of XML, is it that this is a limitation and only xmls without prefix can be parsed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254359/discussion-between-nishantm-and-nbk).